# how to get the distance betwween two points from google maps url api 

Tags: google-maps, distance

i use google maps api v2 ,  and i know the method `distanceFrom` can get the distance ,

but i want to get the distance and then store it into database ,

it has a easy way like this :

```
http://ditu.google.cn/maps/geo?q=39.88509,116.336355&output=xml&sensor=true_or_false&key=abcdefg
```

i visit this url and get the response using django , and then store it into mysql ,

now i want to get the distance , Does google has the **url** api ,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using standard latitude/longitude calculations:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103715/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/sets/select/dm_lat_long.html)

Store latitude and longitude in your database.